# AngularJS - How to pass name of NgModel as parameter in a function then access it with $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

So, I am listening to the `NgKeyup` event, which fires a function that receives the current `NgModel` as follows:

```
<input ng-model="__name" ng-keyup="filterValue(this.__name, 'stringMax100')" type="text" name="unit-income-name" class="form-control" id="unit-income-name" maxlength="100" required>
```

`this.__name` is equivalent to the `$scope.__name` (as `ng-keyup` is an event from angular, this is the `$scope`)

Once, my function returns an error it enables a flag that shows an error. In this case, I know what the name of the `NgModel` is, but what if I don't know it?

I would like to pass the name of the `NgModel` as parameter and the evaluate it within the function, this is my idea:

```
<input ng-model="__somethingElse1" ng-keyup="filterValue('__somethingElse1', 'stringMax100')" type="text">

<input ng-model="__somethingElse2" ng-keyup="filterValue('__somethingElse2', 'stringMax100')" type="text">

<input ng-model="__somethingElse3" ng-keyup="filterValue('__somethingElse3', 'stringMax100')" type="text">
```

And from the code:

```
$scope.filterValue = function(ngModelName, type, $event){

    $scope.eval(ngModelName)
    // Or
    eval($scope.ngModelName)

};
```

Or something like that, I am using "eval" as an example.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scope's `$eval` method:

```
$scope.filterValue = function(ngModelName, type, $event){

    //works for simple names
    //$scope[ngModelName];

    //works for complex names, '$ctrl.x', 'x[$index]', etc.
    console.log($scope.$eval(ngModelName));

};
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference - $eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, in my case it would be:

```
$scope.filterValue = function(ngModelName, type, $event){

    $scope[ngModelName]

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your real case is different but I don't see a need of evaluating the name in your example code.

```
<input ng-model="__name" ng-keyup="filterValue(__name, 'stringMax100')" type="text" name="unit-income-name" class="form-control" id="unit-income-name" maxlength="100" required>

$scope.filterValue = function(model, type, $event) {
    console.log(model);
};
```

Comment: In my case, I don't know always the name of the ng-model as they are dynamically created, so I need to dynamically pass it. But thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter I think. You always need to refer your `ng-model` by some variable, and you pass that same variable into the function

Comment: I actually tried it, didn't work. It's a little more complicated because of the way of how its created. Thanks a lot anyway.